# Handling Missing Not at Random type of Missing Data

Tags: missing-data

I'm working on University Enrollment dataset and trying to predict whether an individual who is admitted will enroll or not. One of the variables in it is the scholarship test. This variable has the scholarship test score in it as well as missing values. I understand from the data that the missing values in this particular variable means that the individual did not take the test So my question is how should I handle this missing data? As per my understanding, this can be considered as Missing not at random type of missing data, since the missing values denote that the individual did not take the test. Can I replace the missing values with 0 because the data points are numeric ? Will that impact the model in any way? The model I'm planning to use is SVM and Random Forest.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, what question are you trying to answer? Do you assume that the test reflects some underlying property of the people that gets measured by the test (perhaps imperfectly with noise) and you want to reflect that? If so, imputing by zero is certainly a bad idea. Or do you want to answer whether not taking the test predicts admission (perhaps in that case encoding no test by zero could be an idea, if that's not a score you would normally not get - alternatively you could also/additionally have a flag for missing result).

Secondly, you'll have to understand why the variable is missing. E.g. if only those that passed an interview (or got some offer or thought they had some chance or fulfilled some grade average etc.) even took the test, this is a really tricky situation, because you would not have an observed values for a certain type of person. While that would technically be a missing at random assumption, you'd have to make assumptions about these people that would be to some extent untestable. However, ignoring the people with missing values would be even worse than making sensible assumptions. Perhaps in that case some multiple imputation could perhaps end up doing something sensible.

On the other hand, if the occasional person misses a test because they happened to be ill on the day or something like that, then that would be a convenient missing completely at random situation (that's the one situation where leaving out the records with missingness is okay, but still inefficient). Missing not at random would occur e.g. if people took the test and then decided based on the results to tell the university or not (or perhaps if people can to some extent predict their likely score and are more likely to take the test, if they predict a better outcome).

Both SVM and RF would heavily be affected by how you handle the missing values (in fact every model would be affected).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. My question is if someone who took the scholarship test, did they also enroll when they were given an admit to the university? The lower end of the range starts at 9 for this variable, this made me think if someone who did not take the test at all can be scored as zero. Would it help if I create another variable based on this one, that indicates in binary if someone took the test or not and disregard the score of the scholarship test?